# How we know only N independent vectors are enough to span any N dimensional vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have three vectors which are linearly independent. So they would be able to span a 3 dimensional vector space. But how we are sure that number 3 would be enough to span 3-D vector space or in general N independent vectors are enough to span a N dimensional space?
Actually I am looking for some intuition and a rigorous mathematical proof .

Comment: In a nutshell - too many vectors and some are linear combinations of others and can be thrown out. Too few, and one can find some $x$ in the space that is not in the span of that set.

Comment: Suppose $W$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $\dim(W)=3=\dim(V)$. Further suppose there is some $v\in V$ that doesn't belong to $W$. Can you show that $\{w_1,w_2,w_3,v\}$ is linearly independent, where $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ is a basis for $W$? What does this mean?

Comment: It's essentially the definition of "dimension", and the standard Exchange Theorem (aka Replacement theorem) showing that the dimension is well-defined. This is covered in multiple posts in this site: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1299952/742), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2498608/742), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/422534/742), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2546046/742), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/155410/742), among many other places.